# Reduce plot size of Flexdashboard storyboard

Tags: r, plot, plotly, storyboard, flexdashboard

I am creating a Flexdashboard storyboard and am finding my storyboards require a small scroll but I would like to not have to scroll. How can I reduce the size of my plots to ensure no scroll is required?
Thanks